# Negation regex is not working as expected

Tags: regex

I expect the regex `(?!(\sI\s))` to match with all the characters in the string `HELLO I TEST` except the `I`. But it doesn't seem to work that way. Was trying out [here](https://regex101.com/r/rMbYHz/316).
I expect the pattern to match all characters except the one mentioned in the negation, but it doesn't seems so any help on understanding this would be helpful.

Comment: Split with `/\sI\s/`

Comment: You are not matching anything with the lookahead assertion. Else try `(?!(I))[A-Z]`

Comment: Can you clarify how your expectation differs from your result? In the link you posted, we can see a match everywhere except directly in front of " I "? Are you saying that you'd expect the missing match to be in front of the "I" instead of in front of the space (or both)? Or are you saying that you'd expect the matches to actually contain characters rather than just being lines / empty matches?

Comment: @Thefourthbird That works, but when `(?!)` mean anything but, why should I explicitly mention [A-Z]?

Comment: @sepp2k Yes I'm expecting to match all words except the word ` I `

Comment: You can't match anything but a multicharacter string. In PCRE, there is a hack: `(?s)multi-word-pattern(*SKIP)(*F)|(?:(?!multi-word-pattern).)+`. Split with the pattern, and if needed, join the resulting chunks with a string method.

Comment: Splitting would be easier indeed, or `\b(?!I\b)\w+` to match words that are not `I`

Comment: @KannanRamamoorthy That didn't make it clearer for me. Which of my specific questions did you say "yes" to? Is it about the length of the matches or the position of the missing match?